# How to find modules dependency & install it but without cpan/cpanm?

Tags: perl, cpan, openshift

The problem is I don't have access to write $HOME directory. (I only have access to create new directory on $HOME/app-root/data/)

because cpan/cpanm need to create new directory $HOME/.cpan/  I don't have idea how to find all modules dependency by hand (one-by-one).

Do you guys know other method to install module (and find dependency) but without to create  ~/.cpan/ directory ?

or maybe how to override ~/.cpan/ to ~/app-root/data/.cpan ?

P.S: Sorry my english is bad, english isn't my native language

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just (temporarily) change `$HOME` to a directory you *do* have write access to:

```
HOME=$HOME/app-root/data/ cpanm Module
```

Answer (score 4):

[An answer to the literal question is useful to people trying to install on a machine without internet, so I'll answer it even though it's not the best solution for you.]

To find the dependencies, you can use http://deps.cpantesters.org/. For example, here's the dependency tree for [a module of mine](http://deps.cpantesters.org/?module=Syntax%3A%3AFeature%3A%3ALoop&perl=5.16.3&os=any+OS).

Answer (score 1):

Just list modules you need in .openshift/cpan.txt
Openshift will install it automatically when you deploy